# Krusader: how to open .xpi file like .zip?

Tags: zip, file-association, krusader

In Krusader, I can enter a .zip (or .tar etc.) file as if it were a directory, and view/copy/etc. the files in the archive.

How can I tell Krusader to do the same for .xpi files (which are really just zip files with a .xpi extension)?

Currently, pressing enter or double-clicking an .xpi launches firefox, which prompts for the install of the extension. This is probably due to `.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` containing

```
application/x-xpinstall=firefox.desktop;
```

and/or `.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop` containing

```
MimeType=... application/x-xpinstall;
```

(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Krusader 2.4.0-beta3)

Comment: Just make a copy of the archive changing .xpi to .zip. That'll be easier than teaching Krusader new tricks.

Comment: @DK-Bose Yes, of course, but that is cumbersome.

Comment: How often do you need to do this? Dolphin can open .xpi files with Ark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old question but maybe some googler will benefit from this answer. Most likely this is not possible by configuration, but a workaround is like this:

When an `.xpi` file (or actually any other zip with custom extension) is highlighted, copy its path (`ctrl+c` works for me), then go to the location bar (`ctrl+l`), type `zip://` and paste the path. The correct url will be then:

```
zip:///path/to/file.xpi
```

After pressing enter Krusader will open the zip file and show its contents.

Comment: Excellent. When copy/pasting, I already get `file:///` at the start. I only need to overwrite "file" with "zip".